# What is the best way to toilet train a puppy?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

My friend's dog uses the restroom on his carpet a lot, and he's already tried lots of methods to get it to stop. Does anyone know an effective way to toilet train a puppy?

Comment: when you say "toilet" train, you mean getting the puppy to go inside the toilet?

Comment: Also make sure that you use a special urine remover and not bleach to remove the stain from the carpet. Normal cleaning products will not remove the underlying smell of ammonia (an ingredient in bleach and urine).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has not described any details of their living arrangements, apartment, house? The set up, the age of the puppy, breed. Relevants things that can assist in tailoring answers


Comment: This question came up for review to reopen. I'm not voting to do so with the question as-is: I don't believe it's off-topic, but without more specific details like what has already been tried, it is too broad.

Comment: @toxotes I totally agree. It is about someone else's pet and is vague, as well as broad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had a lot of success with crate training.

Dogs won't relieve themselves where they sleep or eat. Keeping them in an enclosed area and bringing them outside when they have to go to relieve themselves teaches them where it's OK to do so.

I recommend buying an expandable crate. You want to give them just enough room to stand up and turn around, but not enough that they'll start going in the corner. As they grow you can increase the size of the crate accordingly.

The Humane Society has some [great info](http://www.humanesociety.org/animals/dogs/tips/crate_training.html) on crate training.

Comment: +1 While I have no personal experience with crate training, it works well for overnight for most people I have heard trying it. Just be aware that your puppy will only be able to hold it for so many hours overnight, depending on its age.

Answer (score 5):

@Paperjam is right: crate training is probably the most effective way to quickly housetrain a puppy.

I will also add that *routine* is incredibly important when house-training a puppy.

Take your dog out on a schedule: the same times, every day.  Also try to take them out shortly after they eat: puppies might have to go as shortly as 30 minutes after a meal.  You want to set your pup up for success.

Lastly, let me emphasize that **accidents will happen**.  It's natural, it's frustrating, but it's not the end of the world.  What you *don't* want to do is scold your puppy, or "rub their nose in it".  Dogs don't really learn that way, and usually just ape your emotions to appease you when they can't figure out what's wrong. It's better to try and prevent such accidents from happening, rather than reacting to one that's already transpired.

Comment: +1 Also, learn to read how your dog signals it needs to go. Usually, it'll lose interest in whatever it was doing and start sniffing intently. Your dog needs to learn that it can tell you it needs to go and that you will respond to that need. Scolding and rubbing its nose will only serve to make sure it'll go when you can't see it and where you can't find it.